# How do I customise the product search results page on a woocommerce website?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, storefront

I want to edit the html of the product results posts in my woocommerce storefront child theme.

Under search.php it says:

```
get_template_part( 'loop' );
```

Then under loop.php it says:

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

Which then takes me to content.php which contains:

```
do_action( 'storefront_loop_post' );
```

So do I need to edit the functions inside that action? If so how?

Quite new to using child themes.

Comment: Really need a hand with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside content.php, I commented out the storefront_loop_post hook and created my own action which I then referenced.

Works a treat